# Printing on same line for Python

Tags: python, newline

Hi I am very new to Python and I have been learning to create a Blackjack game. I want to print the cards on the same row, instead of on a new line each time. How should I go about doing this?

[Current Output]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7ELY.png

Code for output is below:

```
def show(self):
  print('┌───────┐')
  print(f'| {self.value:<2}    |')
  print('|       |')
  print(f'|   {self.suit}   |')
  print('|       |')
  print(f'|    {self.value:>2} |')
  print('└───────┘')
```

Answer (score 0):

> By default Python‘s print() function ends with a newline. A programmer with C/C++ background may wonder how to print without a newline. Python’s print() function comes with a parameter called ‘end‘. By default, the value of this parameter is ‘\n’, i.e. the new line character.

```
print("This line will be", end = ' ')
print("printed in same line", end= ' ')
```